# Check if an element is empty after using .append

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a table body (`tbody`) is empty using jQuery. So far I've tried something like:

```js
$("#searchTable tbody").is(":empty")
```

But it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

HTML Sample

```
<table id="searchTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th><a href="#">Status</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="asc">Category</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="desc">Title</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="desc">Last Used</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="desc">URL</a></th>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

So I want to check if something was appended in tbody; if not, then alert something.

Comment: In what way does it fail to work? Could we see a sample of the HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like

```
$('#searchTable tbody').children().length;
```

Which will be 0 if tbody is empty (has no children).

Comment: That's exactly what `.is(":empty")` does, right? Or do text nodes not count as children? The OP's error is more likely in flow than in the `:empty` selector not doing its job correctly.

Comment: Just tried it out, and .children().length does not count text nodes. If you .append('text'), then .children().length will give zero, while if you append('<tr><td>text</td></tr>'), then children().length will give one. In either case, .is(':empty') returns false.

It's worked for me, how exactly is it not working for you? "Not working..." isn't exactly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the element is not found, it will return false too. Check is the element is present and is selectable using your selector.